# what can I do after being scammed

Tags: theft, data-ownership, computer-misuse-act

I traded a Domain name (http://stamp.wtf) for a year of hosting by a man.

After (permanently) transfering the domain to the man, he set up an account for.

He then deleted it a few days later (yesterday or today) before I got the chance to make use of the server, because I was writing the code for my application on my own computer.

Is there any legal action I can take?

Before we traded, I asked him to make a contract, but he said "[he] wouldnt make a contract for a $7 domain".

I'm also under 18.

He has blocked and ignore all attempts at communication.

Answer (score 3):

It seems that you have a valid contract and he has breached it. You could sue for the value of a year's hosting in a small claims court. Whether this is worth the effort ...

Comment: I checked and the fee in the U.K is more than the domain price. Also, this man is in the U.S.

Comment: Yes. The important lesson here is: don't deal with crooks.

Answer (score 1):

Alternatively, since you are under 18, you can void the contract. Which means you would have no right to a year's hosting, and he would have no right to the domain name, and if he uses it, you can take him to court.

BTW. If he hasn't "made a contract for a $7 domain" then he hasn't got a right to that domain name anyway. No contract, no rights.

Comment: The name's already his, there's nothing I can do.